# Safari keeps crashing after updating to Big Sur. Termination Reason: Namespace ASSERTIOND

Tags: macos, safari, crash, big-sur

After I upgraded to MacOS Big Sur, Safari started to crash and the crash logs look very similar.

Sometimes it would crash when I click a link, sometimes it would crash when not doing anything. Often I would notice that Safari crashed when I was away from my computer.

The message is about the same every time:

```
System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace ASSERTIOND, Code 0xd00d2bad

Application Specific Information:
Enabled App Extensions:
com.Tab-Suspender.Extension (DZ2G3D39GP) (Version: 39 - Display Version: 2.1.1) Tab Suspender
com.adguard.safari.AdGuard.AdvancedBlocking (TC3Q7MAJXF) (Version: 48 - Display Version: 1.8.10) AdGuard Advanced Blocking
de.APPenzeller.PiPifier.PiPifier-Safari-Extension (AW9CBV6SY7) (Version: 8 - Display Version: 1.2.4) PiPifier Button
com.adguard.safari.AdGuard.Extension (TC3Q7MAJXF) (Version: 48 - Display Version: 1.8.10) AdGuard Safari Icon
 
Enabled Content Blockers:
com.adguard.safari.AdGuard.BlockerExtension (TC3Q7MAJXF) (Version: 48 - Display Version: 1.8.10) AdGuard General
com.adguard.safari.AdGuard.BlockerSecurity (TC3Q7MAJXF) (Version: 48 - Display Version: 1.8.10) AdGuard Security
com.adguard.safari.AdGuard.BlockerCustom (TC3Q7MAJXF) (Version: 48 - Display Version: 1.8.10) AdGuard Custom
com.adguard.safari.AdGuard.BlockerOther (TC3Q7MAJXF) (Version: 48 - Display Version: 1.8.10) AdGuard Other
com.adguard.safari.AdGuard.BlockerPrivacy (TC3Q7MAJXF) (Version: 48 - Display Version: 1.8.10) AdGuard Privacy
com.adguard.safari.AdGuard.BlockerSocial (TC3Q7MAJXF) (Version: 48 - Display Version: 1.8.10) AdGuard Social
```

Any ideas how to debug this or what it could be?

Thanks.

Comment: Same problem here. Deactivating all Safari extensions seems to have resolved -- but obviously unsatisfactory for long term use.  Still trying to isolate which extension is the problem by turning them on one at a time.  I suspect a OS-level bug in some Safari extension API, because this problem also started to happen the day I upgraded to Big Sur.

Comment: I've had the same problem and disabling AdGuard seems to have resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Disabling AdGuard seems to work but I want to use ad blockers so I installed 1 Blocker. First it looked good but Safari crashed again.

Comment: Same problem here. AdGuard is disabled, but it Safari keeps crashing

Comment: @BikPengu what is your system? A non-retina air by any chance?

Comment: It stopped crashing after I removed all the extensions, so it wasn't just about the content blockers. The more extensions I had the often would have happened and completely stopped happening with no extensions. It seems like a bug with the new extension system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems fixed as of MacOS 11.2